# How to display XML tag which has - in it using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having following powershell script

```
$MyVM= [XML] @"
<VM>
  <IPAddress>X.Y.Z.T</IPAddress>
  <VMName>R2-VM</VMName>
  <Vsphere-host>X.X.X.X</Vsphere-host>
  <OS>W2K8-R2</OS>        
  <AssignedTo>Tester</AssignedTo>
</VM>
"@

Write-host " Your VM details"
Write-host "------------------"
Write-host "IPaddress: " $MyVM.VM.IPAddress
Write-host "Host Machine IP:" $MyVM.VM.Vsphere-host
```

Instead of displaying Vsphere host information it simply displays as follows

```
 Host Machine IP: System.Xml.XmlDocument.VM.Vsphere-host
```

how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `Vsphere-host` between quotes like this: `"Vsphere-host"`

```
$MyVM= [XML] @"
<VM>
  <IPAddress>X.Y.Z.T</IPAddress>
  <VMName>R2-VM</VMName>
  <Vsphere-host>X.X.X.X</Vsphere-host>
  <OS>W2K8-R2</OS>        
  <AssignedTo>Tester</AssignedTo>
</VM>
"@

Write-host " Your VM details"
Write-host "------------------"
Write-host "IPaddress: " $MyVM.VM.IPAddress
Write-host "Host Machine IP:" $MyVM.VM."Vsphere-host"
```